# Laplace transform, when $s \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

I'm reviewing lecture notes on Laplace Transform and there's one step that I don't understand:

Find the solution to:
$$x y'' + y' + xy = 0, y(0) = 1, y'(0) \mbox{ finite}$$
Taking the Laplace Transform, we get:
\begin{align}
0 &= (-s^2 - 1) Y'(s) + (-2s + s) Y(s) \\
(s^2 + 1) Y'(s) &= -s Y(s) \\
\frac{Y'(s)}{Y(s)} &= -\frac{s}{s^2 + 1} \\
\log(Y(s)) &= - \int \frac{s}{s^2 + 1} ds \\
 &= -\frac{1}{2} \log(s^2 + 1) + C \\
Y(s) &= \frac{D}{\sqrt{s^2 + 1}}
\end{align}

To find D, let:
$$\frac{D}{\sqrt{s^2 + 1}} = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-xs} y(x) dx \rightarrow \frac{y(0)}{s} \mbox{as $s \rightarrow \infty$}$$
which then yields $D = 1$

So this is where I don't understand; how can we approximate the integral to $\frac{y(0)}{s}$ as $s \rightarrow \infty$?